# updating embedded linux using swupdate and is there any other projects related to same?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, swupdate

Hi i am wondering if there is any projects similiar to swupdate in linux for updating linux. I have tried understanding the swupdate the swupdate documentation seems so vague. if there is any can any one list any on them it would be a great help. Thanks in advance

i tried installing swupdate on a linux based board and tried to run it but it was giving following error.

```
SWUpdate v2023.05

Licensed under GPLv2. See source distribution for detailed copyright notices.

[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_bootloaders] : Registered bootloaders:
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_bootloaders] : none loaded.
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [main] : Using default bootloader interface: none
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_handlers_init] : External Lua handler(s) not found.
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : Lua exception:
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : [string "require ("swupdate_handlers")"]:1: module 'swupdate_handlers' not found:
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no field package.preload['swupdate_handlers']
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/swupdate_handlers.lua'
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/swupdate_handlers/init.lua'
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/swupdate_handlers.lua'
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/swupdate_handlers/init.lua'
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/swupdate_handlers.lua'
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/swupdate_handlers/init.lua'
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no file './swupdate_handlers.lua'
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/swupdate_handlers.so'
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no file '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lua/5.2/swupdate_handlers.so'
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/swupdate_handlers.so'
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [lua_report_exception] : no file './swupdate_handlers.so'
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_handlers] : Registered handlers:
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_handlers] : dummy
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_handlers] : archive
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_handlers] : tar
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_handlers] : lua
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_handlers] : raw
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_handlers] : rawfile
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_handlers] : remote
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_handlers] : shellscript
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_handlers] : preinstall
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running : [print_registered_handlers] : postinstall
[DEBUG] : SWUPDATE running : [read_module_settings] : No config settings found for module versions
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [listener_create] : creating socket at /tmp/swupdateprog
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [network_initializer] : Main loop daemon
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [listener_create] : creating socket at /tmp/sockinstctrl
[DEBUG] : SWUPDATE running : [read_module_settings] : No config settings found for module webserver
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running : [start_swupdate_subprocess] : Started webserver with pid 6406 and fd 8
swupdate: invalid option -- 'd'
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR pctl.c : start_swupdate_subprocess : 220 : Spawning webserver failed, exiting process..
```